# Recursion with return types

Tags: recursion, binary-tree

How to understand complex recursions? I just find the beginner level recursion examples. I wanted to know how to understand recursion and the call stack when complex logic is involved.

```
 public Boolean recursion(int value, string name)
    {
        if (value > 10 && value<12)
            return false;

        if (value > 110)
            return false;

        if (value > 104 && value < 106)
            return false;
        return recursion(value+1,"left") || recursion(value+100,"right");
    }
```

or to be precise the following logic

```
 public bool HasPathSum(TreeNode root, int sum) {
 if (root == null)
    return false;
if (root.val == sum && (root.left == null && root.right == null))
    return true;

return HasPathSum(root.left, sum - root.val)
        || HasPathSum(root.right, sum - root.val);
}
```

How do i understand the flow of the above sample recursive function?

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is a little tricky, you need to keep track every time the function is called. In each invocation, a separate stack is made.

Specifically, for the second function, it is checking if the sum of the root to leaf path nodes is equal to particular value. The OR `||` condition is there because the path can either be in left or right subtree - if any one satisfies it s a `true`.

The line `if (root.val == sum && (root.left == null && root.right == null))` checks that till you reach the leaf, is the `sum` equal to the `value`. Also notice that the `value` is decreased and then used to call recursively, because a `node` is considered and its value has been taken into consideration, the rest of the nodes from this node to the leaf must have the sum less than the original sum ( less by the current node's value ).